# Maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ with $f(x|\theta) = -(\theta+\theta^2)(1+x)^{\theta-1}x, -1<x<0, \theta>0 $

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from the pdf $f(x|\theta) =  -(\theta+\theta^2)(1+x)^{\theta-1}x, -1<x<0, \theta>0,$ zero elsewhere.

How could I deal with the negative sign when I take partial derivative w.r.t $\theta$ ?

Comment: Just treat it as a constant.

Comment: Your title is too long and does not agree with the body of the post. The hint below assumes you're looking for the MLE of $\theta$ not of $f(x|\theta)$.

Comment: Just compute $\Pi f$ and take logs $\sum log(f)$. Do your straighforward computations and pose derivate $=0$. You get $\sum g(\theta) = \sum log(1+x_1)$ RHS is a constant. LHS are $N$ summands all equal to each other, where $g(\theta)$ is a ratio of two polynomials in $\theta$ of degree 1 and 2. Solve this equation of order 2 and pick the $\theta$ which is $>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: let $A=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)$ and $B=\prod_{i=1}^n(-x_i)$. You're to find $\theta$ that maximizes
$$
(\theta+\theta^2)A^{\theta-1}B.
$$
Since $\theta$ cannot affect $B>0$, you can just maximize $(\theta+\theta^2)A^{\theta-1}$. Taking derivative:
$$
\partial_\theta((\theta+\theta^2)A^{\theta-1})=A^{\theta-1}[1+\theta(2+\log A)+\theta^2\log A].
$$
When setting the RHS above to $0$, you don't need to worry about $A^{\theta-1}$ so what remains to select the positive root of the quadratic in square brackets above.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I deal with the negative sign...

If you mean the restricion $\theta >0$ : that only gives you the domain of your variable: $\theta$ is restricted to $(0,+\infty)$. To find the (global) maximum of a real function you do as usual: if the function is derivable in all its domain, you find the critical points and check if they are indeed local extremes. Of course, you must only consider the critical points (zeroes of the derivative) that lie inside your domain. That's where the restriction  $\theta >0$ comes into play.

Also (this is important) you must check if your local maxima is really a global maximum (in particular, look at your domain boundary).